# HTML data extraction

Tags: html, regex, groovy, extract

I'm accessing some website and I need to extract some data. To be more specific - from this part:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="d520783895194bd08750e47c744d553d">
```

I need to extract the "name" part. I heard that reular expressions are not the best solution, so I'd like to ask what is the best way to access this piece of data I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After parsing a website with NekoHTML or TagSoup (which should take care of the fact that your input field tag is not closed), I suggest to use a xpath expression:

```
//input[@type='hidden'][@value=1]/@name
```

In groovy you will apply it in form of [GPath](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GPath).

Answer (score 2):

Use a Html parsing library, they fix malformed Html a make it easy to navigate the document to find and update elements. Here is a link to a list of Java/Groovy implementations:

http://www.wavyx.net/2009/01/13/looking-for-a-java-html-parser-or-groovy/

Looks like [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) and [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) are popular, but I haven't used either or Groovy for that matter. But I have used Html Parsers in other languages.